# Can not install WOLips Goodies Eclipse Plugin on CentOS 6

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, webobjects

So, I'm using CentOS 6 desktop to do WebObjects development. Normally I do WO development on Mac, but our office only has Linux-based desktops so I'm going through the hassle of getting the team set up with the appropriate development environment. Anyway, when I try to install WOLips Goodies plugin through Eclipse I get the following error:

> "Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
>     org.objectstyle.wolips.goodies.feature.feature.group [3.7.1006251] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable."

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? Or maybe can you tell me where to look to find the missing dependencies?